# expectation for Black-Scholes martingale

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, finance, martingales

Say you have a standard GBM for the underlying asset price for Black-Scholes, written as a martingale:

$d\hat{S}/\hat{S} = \sigma d\hat{B}(t)$.

If you wanted an expression for $\hat{S}(0)$, is this just by Martingales:

$\hat{S}(0) = \mathbb{E}[\hat{S}(T) | \hat{S}(0)]$ ?

This is strange to me, because it is saying to find $\hat{S}(0)$, you have to know what $\hat{S}(0)$ is, as your expectation is conditioned on it, or is my interpretation incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct (as you say, it's just an expression of the martingale property), but you seem to be having some confusion on its interpretation. Usually we would write it the other way: $$ E[S(T)\mid S(0)] = S(0),$$ in other words, we're computing the LHS based on the RHS. This is because $S(0)$ usually represents the stock price right now, which is a known quantity. The left hand side is the expected value of the stock at time $T$ in the future given that we know the stock price now. The equation says that the average price at time $T$ is just the price right now.

So yes when you write an equation like that, since the LHS is conditioned on $S(0)$ you're generally assuming you know the value of $S(0).$ Actually, that's not strictly true, though. If we were sitting at time $-1$ or something and didn't know yet what $S(0)$ was, the equation $E[S(T)\mid S(0)] =S(0)$ would still be true and make sense. What it says is, roughtly, "once I know the value of $S(0)$ (which is a random variable) the value it takes will be the expected value of the price at time $T$."

Note that still this is not a way to "calculate" $S(0)$ (it is random). What you can calculate, though, is its expected value given what you know now: $E[S(0)\mid S(-1)] = S(-1)$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your detailed answer. But, when pricing options in martingale theory, isn't the point to find say V(0) based on V(T)?

Comment: Ahh, I see where you're coming from now. Yeah, in that case $S(0) = E[S(T)\mid S(0)]$ is a (trivial) pricing equation for the stock right now. But for a nontrivial derivative, you'd have $V(0) = E[V(T)\mid S(0)]$ which doesn't face your criticism cause we do know $S(0)$ right now (but we don't know the derivative price right now). And since the risk neutral measure must price all derivatives correctly, it better do the trivial derivative (just the underlying) right as well.

Comment: So given that then, could one just write: $S(0) = \mathbb{E}[S(T)]$, and interpret this to say the initial price is just the expected value of what you "want" the price to be at $S(T)$?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the way to look at it. Keep in mind that the expected value here is with respect to the pricing distribution for $S$, not the 'actual distribution'. It might be that we actually expect the return on the stock to be on average very high, but it's trading cheap cause it's very risky or for some other reason. Since the pricing distribution needs to get today's observed prices right, the (discounted) stock price will necessarily be a martingale under the pricing distribution, even if we really might expect a large drift in reality.